# RecyclerView is not working properly, items are duplicating and keep changing constantly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

when I start scrolling some items are getting repeated, not showing the proper result, and I've tried literally everything like overriding these methods in the `Adapter` class:

```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return super.getItemViewType(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return super.getItemId(position);
   }
```

and even I've also tried passing `setHasStableIds(true)` in the constructor but failed to get the desired results.

This is my `Adapter` class

```
public class NickzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {




    private List<PhotozData> list;
    private Context context;
    private NickzViewHolder holder;

    public NickzAdapter(Context context, List<PhotozData> list) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent, false);
        holder = new NickzViewHolder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        this.holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        //Log.d("Bind name",list.get(position).getName());
        Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImageUri()).into(this.holder.photo);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();

    }


}
```

And this is my `ViewHolder` class

```
public class NickzViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView photo;
    public TextView name, date, time;

    public NickzViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_date);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_name);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_time);
    }
```

I would appreciate your help, Thank you

Comment: Can you post a gif to show what is actually happening ?? @Nick

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10N5q71J83bH9IBZcjgkBuMBwdt9SNM_k/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this code inside your NickzViewHolder class: `this.setIsRecyclable(false);`
this is just one of several ways to solve that problem

Comment: but then, what would be the use of RecycleView if you are disabling its ability to recycle?

Comment: RecyclerView is not only about recycling, it is also about easy way to implement custom view in every row. So this method works just fine for not long lists. You can also try this in your adapter: @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {    
    return position;
} - this also gonna work and your RecyclerView will keep ability to recycle

Comment: Okay! THANK YOU SOO MUCH

Comment: You are welcome. Can you choose my answer as a right one?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Layout Inflater is not getting the proper context to inflate. Try changing your

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
```

Comment: hey, thank you for the quick reply, but it didn't work

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10N5q71J83bH9IBZcjgkBuMBwdt9SNM_k/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: This is how it's behaving

Comment: only that particular position is fluctuating?

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

               holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
               holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            //Log.d("Bind name",list.get(position).getName());
            Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImageUri()).into(holder.photo);

            }
```

[linke](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#setisrecyclable)

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much, it worked!!, but what would be the use of RecycleView if you are disabling its ability to recycle?